# How to integrate paypal pro with ubercart?

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I'm new to ubercart. How to integrate PalPal Pro in ubercart? thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit confusing and not well documented.  Ubercart (in Drupal) will list PayPal Standard and PayPal Express as Payment METHODS, but PayPal Pro appears only as a payment gateway.

You need to choose "credit card" as your payment method, and use PayPal Pro as your gateway.

You will need to get API credentials.  This page at Ubercart has details:
http://www.ubercart.org/paypal